# Matrix optimization over a quadratic function

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find matrices $F$, $G$, and $H$ minimizing

$\begin{bmatrix} 
x^T & y^T& z^T 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
I & 0& 0 \\
0 & F &0 \\
0 & G &H 
\end{bmatrix}^{T} Q \begin{bmatrix} 
I & 0& 0 \\
0 & F &0 \\
0 & G &H 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\ y \\ z 
\end{bmatrix}
$

as a function of $x,y,z$ and symmetric positive definite matrix $Q$ given as

$\begin{bmatrix} 
Q_{11} & Q_{12}& Q_{13} \\
Q_{21} & Q_{22} &Q_{23} \\
Q_{31} & Q_{32} &Q_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}$ where $Q_{ij}$ matrices are with appropriate dimensions.

All $x,y,z$ are column vectors with the size of $n$ and $I$ denotes identity matrix. Can anybody give me some hints about how we can solve such a problem?

The problem can be written as

$\begin{bmatrix} 
x^T & y^T& z^T 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
Q_{11} & Q_{12}F + Q_{13}G& Q_{13}H \\
F^T Q_{21} + G^T Q_{31} & F^T Q_{22}F + F^T Q_{23} G + G^T Q_{32}F + G^T Q_{33} G & F^T Q_{23} H + G^T Q_{23} H \\
H^T Q_{31} & H^T Q_{32} F + H^T Q_{33} G & H^T Q_{33} G 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\ y \\ z 
\end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: So, x,y, and z are fixed?

Comment: To begin with, you could let $Q$ be the identity matrix or a positive diagonal matrix.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp yes, they are fixed.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I rewrote the problem. Do you know what is the method for solving such a problem?

Comment: No, not really. Sorry. However, I think your form is not really well useable since you know nothing about the $Q_{ij}$'s, except they form a positive definite $Q$. Maybe its better to use $Q = UDU^T$ with an orthogonal $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D$.

Comment: Maybe this is clear already, but just in case: The problem is a convex quadratic expression, and thus the optimal solution is given by by a linear system of equations (gradient zero) Hence, brute force is to expand the expression, and derive the gradients w.r.t $F$, $G,$ and $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w = \begin{bmatrix} 
x^T \\ y^T\\ z^T 
\end{bmatrix}$ and $X = \begin{bmatrix} 
I & 0& 0 \\
0 & F &0 \\
0 & G &H 
\end{bmatrix}^T$, and you can write this as $\text{trace}((ww^T)XQX^T)$. Now study [scalar-by-matrix identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) and compare with  $\text{trace}(AXBX^TC)$, and you have $A = ww^T, B = Q, C=I$. The derivative w.r.t $X$ is given by  $B^TX^TA + BX^TA$. Let $S$ define the $0/1$ matrix defining which elements which actually are free to optimize in $X$ (locations corresponding to $F$,$G$,$H$), and you have to solve the linear system of equations $S \circ (B^TX^TA + BX^TA)=0$. For an even more explicit representation, you will have to rewrite this using various kronecker and vectorization tricks.